# Mice eating food.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Two mice (say A and B) eat a piece of food. The rate of consumption for A is proportional to amount of food left (proportionality constant = 2)  and rate of consumption for B is proportional to amount of food eaten by A. (Proportionality constant =1/2). Find

1. The time in which whole of the food will get finished
2. The time when rate of consumption of both the mice will be same.

My approach for this question was to let the consumption of food by A be dF(A)/dT, representing food eaten with respect to A, which will be equal to 2F.And the rate of consumption for B would be dF(B)/dt = 1/2 int(dF(a)/dT) but I couldn't get to the solution using this method. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
Let amount of food initially be $F_0$, and amount of food at any time $t$ be $F(t)$.
Amount of food consumed by $A$ and $B$ till time $t$ be $A(t),B(t)$ respectively.

Rate of consumption by $A$ $${dA(t) \over dt}\propto F(t)\implies {dA(t) \over dt}=2F(t)$$

Rate of consumption by $B$ $${dB(t) \over dt}\propto A(t)\implies {dB(t) \over dt}={1 \over 2}A(t)$$

Rate of consumption of food $$-{dF(t) \over dt}={dA(t) \over dt}+{dB(t) \over dt}=2F(t)+{1 \over 2}A(t)$$

Differentiating wrt $t$,
$$-{d^2 F(t) \over dt^2}=2{dF(t) \over dt}+{1 \over 2}{dA(t) \over dt} \\
-{d^2 F(t) \over dt^2}=2{dF(t) \over dt}+F(t)\\
F(t)=c_1 e^{-t} + c_2 e^{-t} t
$$
for some arbitrary constants $c_1,c_2$

Initially, $F(0)=F_0,\; c_1=F_0,$
$$F(t)=e^{-t}(F_0+c_2 t)$$

Let time when food is completely consumed be $t=t_c\;F(t_c)=0$
$$0=e^{-t_c}(F_0+c_2 t_c)\\
F_0+c_2 t_c=0 \\
t_c= -{F_0 \over c_2}$$

How to proceed further? The answer is $t_c=1$ when food is finished, and $t=0.66$ when rate pf consumption by $A$ equals that of by $B$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  What is $F$?  If $F$ is supposed to be the amount of food left, then note that that amount is going down because of *two* factors, not one.  Both of the mice are eating, after all.

Comment: More broadly, what you have written is very vague.  Shouldn't $F'$ be negative?  I suggest:  write out everything you have done carefully, defining all your terms precisely.  I think that should help clarify things.

Comment: I just realized that [the edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4769987/2) by @HarshSharma, which caused the reopening of the post, considerably betrayed the OP's intention, who didn't show at all such calculations.

Answer (score 1):

$$A'=2(F_0-A-B),\quad B'=\frac A2,\quad A(0)=B(0)=0\iff$$
$$B=F_0-A-\frac{A'}2,\quad\left(F_0-A-\frac{A'}2\right)'=\frac A2,\quad A(0)=B(0)=0\iff$$
$$A''+2A'+A=0,\quad B=F_0-A-\frac{A'}2,\quad A(0)=B(0)=0\iff$$
$$A(t)=Cte^{-t},\quad B(t)=F_0-\frac C2(t+1)e^{-t},\quad B(0)=0\iff$$
$$A(t)=2F_0te^{-t},\quad B(t)=F_0(1-(t+1)e^{-t}).$$

1. $A(t)+B(t)=F_0\iff 2te^{-t}+1-(t+1)e^{-t}=1\iff t=1.$
2. $A'(t)=B'(t)\iff2(1-t)=t\iff t=\frac23.$